# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.SF

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated my Android Studio to 2.1, after that I got this error and could not run the app again.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.SF
File1: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.38/de366c3243a586eb3c0e2bcde1ed9bb1bfb985ff/bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
File2: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/1.38/14ff2dfec8578f5f6838c4d6a77a86789afe5382/bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
File3: /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bctsp-jdk14/1.38/4821122f8390d15f4b5ee652621e2a2bb1f1bf16/bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
```

I tired to solve this problem by using this lines:

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
```

}

But I got alot of errors such as Font not found, Dialog errors ... etc, also I found that this file `BCKEY.SF` is a main file in Android for Time Stamp Protocol (TSP)

What is that error ?! and how can we solve it ?!